# Generate .record files from xml from labelImg (pascal voc like format) in tensorflow 2

Tags: python, xml, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api, labelimg

I am trying out Tensorflow Object Detection API with a custom dataset and currently hitting a wall with several tutorials at the same place of generation of .record files from xml files.

For image labelling I have used [labelImg](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg) set in Pascal VOC format

There are several scripts out there for a such conversion like in a documentation titled [generate_tfrecord.py](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/tensorflow-1.14/training.html) (it's written as text) but it and a few others fails to run with tensorflow 2 at two outdated lines:

```
# the first 
flags = tf.app.flags
# second at the end of the document
tf.app.run()
```

I could fix first with

```
from absl import app, flags
flags = app.flags
```

but the last one fails even when you use `app.run()` with error `TypeError: run() missing 1 required positional argument: 'main'`

Since I just have a simple custom dataset, I figured I cannot use `object_detection/dataset_tools/create_pascal_tf_record.py` since it requires a year of the pascal dataset and probably also requires specific dataset structure.

Is there a script to generate .record that is working with Tensorflow 2 or could you please point me how to fix those scripts to work with Tensorflow 2 ?